# Resident logic in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I have an ASP.NET web site (blog based on blogengine.net).

I want to perform an integration with Twitter.

I need some logic, that constantly checks, whether I have posted a new twits, and if I did, will create an identical blog post on my site.

This requires a checker object in a separate thread constantly active. Where should I place the instantiation of my classes, so that they are active whenever the ASP.NET web site is working in IIS? Where do I link the logic to my web application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ongoing process shouldn't really be within the scope of the ASP .NET application itself.  An ASP .NET application is more of a request/response system, not a process scheduler.  For an ongoing task which polls an external service and updates data, better options would be:

- A Windows Service
- A console application scheduled with some task scheduler (such as the native Windows one)

One big reason for this is that you never really know if your ASP .NET application is "running."  It can be recycled in the app pool for any number of reasons as the discretion of IIS.  (This is also why putting things in the application start event is a cautious activity, because it's not always known or intuitive when that will be called.)  The application may even be "shut down" if IIS deems it necessary when managing resources, at which point what would happen to your separate thread?

Ideally, what you would have in this case is your ASP .NET application which is backed by a database.  Then you would have a separate application (as above) which updates that same database.  The two need not know anything about each other.